# Column-wise string concatenation of multiple rows in pandas.DataFrame with specific separator

Tags: dataframe, concatenation, series, pandas

is there an **efficient** way to concatenate strings column-wise of multiple rows of a DataFrame such that the result is a single row whose value for each column is the concatenation of each value of the same column of all given rows?

**Example**

Combine the first four rows as explained above.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["this", "this"], ["is", "is"], ["a", "a"], ["test", "test"], ["ignore", "ignore"]])
>>> df
        0       1
0    this    this
1      is      is
2       a       a
3    test    test
4  ignore  ignore
```

Both accepted results:

```
          0              1
0  this is a test  this is a test
```

```
          0
1  this is a test
2  this is a test
```

Answer (score 1):

If need join all rows without last use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
s = df.iloc[:-1].agg(' '.join)
print (s)
0    this is a test
1    this is a test
dtype: object
```

For one row `DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transpose:

```
df = df.iloc[:-1].agg(' '.join).to_frame().T
print (df)
                0               1
0  this is a test  this is a test
```

---

For all rows:

```
s = df.agg(' '.join)
print (s)
0    this is a test ignore
1    this is a test ignore
dtype: object


df = df.agg(' '.join).to_frame().T
print (df)
                       0                      1
0  this is a test ignore  this is a test ignore
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, jezrael. 
I tested it against my solution ```df.iloc[rows, :].apply(lambda column: " ".join(column), axis=0)``` (```rows``` is a list consisting of row indices) and both performed equally well. Maybe we will find an even better solution!

Comment: @cspecial - Yes, it is good solution, similar like my answer, `axis=0` is default value, so should be removed.